# Assign random but even amount from an array to a list array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have two arrays. One array `$People` currently creates number of 44 individuals. Lets just assume currently its

`$People = array('1','2',...,'44');`.

I have another array of 15 elements.

`$Test = array('A','B',...'O');`

Now I want to be able to assign the test randomly to each individual. I know how to do this using random function in php.

Where it has got tricky for me and what I need help with is how can I even out the test array. What I mean by this is since there are currently 44 individuals (this array will grow in future), what I want is 14 test versions to have 3 individuals and 1 version would have 2. So I want the test array to even out. I also want it to handle as growth of `$People` array.

Ex: Test Version D will have individual '4', '25'. Every other version has three random individuals.

Few ideas I came up with are things like running random integer on `$Test` array and which ever gets highest/lowest gets 2 individuals and rest three. This would give a problem when I increase the size of `$People` array; to deal with that I though about using modulus to figure out what will be even number of `$Test` beforehand.

I can do this and other ideas but am pretty sure there has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarifying your situation:**

You want to distribute the values inside `$People` randomly amongst your `$Test` array. The problem you stated you are having is that the amount of values in `$People` isn't always perfectly dividable by the amount of values in `$Test`, and you aren't sure how to go about implementing code to distribute the values evenly.

**Proposed solution:**

You could obtain the values in a `foreach` loop randomly 1 by 1 from a shuffled version of `$People` and put them in a new array called `$Result`. You would also have a conditional checking if you have extracted all the values from the shuffled `$People` array: `if($count>=$arrayCount)` where `$arrayCount=$count($shuffledPeople);`. If you have obtained all the values, you first make the `$bool` value false (in order not to iterate through the `while` loop anymore, and then you `break;` out of the `foreach` loop.

```
$Result =[];//the array containing the results
$shuffledPeople = $People;
shuffle($shuffledPeople);//mixing up the array
$arrayCount = count($shuffledPeople);//finding the total amount of people
$count = 0;
$bool = TRUE;

while ($bool)
{
foreach($Test as $value)
  {
    $Result[$value][] =  $shuffledPeople[$count];
    $count++;
    if ($count>=$arrayCount)
    {
      $bool = FALSE;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

To view the results, all you would need to do is:

```
foreach ($Result as $key => $value)
{
  echo "{$key}: <br>";
  if (is_array($value))
  {
    foreach ($value as $something)
    {
      echo "-->{$something}<br>";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "-->{$value}<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting illegal offset type at '$Result[$Test] = $shuffledPeople[$Count];'

Comment: @USER420 edited my code, forgot to add a `[]` after `$Result[$Test]`

Comment: Still the same error. $Test and $People are both string arrays on my end.

Comment: @USER420 k 1 sec, I'll run the code on my site to see whats up

Comment: This is funny because i was just  going to mentioned its because $Unit is array. Thanks it works.

Comment: @USER420 no problem mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you want to do...

Assume that you have $people and $test arrays. You want to know how many people per test...

```
$ppt = ceil(sizeof($people)/sizeof($test));
```

Now, $ppt is the people per test. The next step is to shuffle up the people so they are randomly assigned to the tests.

```
shuffle($people);
```

Now, we can chunk up the people into sub-arrays such that each sub-array is assigned to a test. Remember, the chunks are random now because we shuffled.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($people, $ppt);
```

Now, everyone in $chunks[0] will take $test[0]. Everyone in $chunks[1] will take $test[1]. Everyone in $chunks[2] will take $test[2].

Comment: Worked for 44. What i did is changed the size of my people array to 34, to see if it will work and it failed there. My $chunks is a two dimensional array with length of 12, wherears my $Test array has length of 14. This would mean two test version of Test are never given out.

Comment: That is by design. With 34 people and 14 tests, the most fair way to divide it is 3 people on 11 tests with 1 person on 1 test. That leaves 2 tests unused. If, instead, you wanted to ensure that every test is used, you use floor instead of ceil when doing the $ppt calculation and you spread the late element of the $chunks array over the tests one by one.